# Android ListView ArrayAdapter notifyDataSetChanged() not always work

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I have an application which connect to a remote server and get data from it.

According to this data i do some changes in my ListView connected objects and i'm using the notifyDataSetChanged() method to refresh my ListView and reflect my changes.

Unfortunately the method not always refresh the list.

the onUpdate() supposed to refresh the list.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate() {
    runOnUiThread(updateClientsInRangeRunnable());  
}

private Runnable updateClientsInRangeRunnable()
{
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateClientsInRangeList(); 
        }
    };
    return run;
}

public void updateClientsInRangeList()
{
    setClientsInRangeList();
    listArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the onUpdate() method is called whenever i want to refresh the list but not always it does it...
the changes made are property changes inside the objects the ListView represt but the changes doesn't refresh only when i'm reloading the ListView

is there a reason why ??

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the code you have shown, but is it possible that setClientsInRangeList() is actually failing to turn up any new data?

Comment: actually it doesn't really do anything... the only this it does is to get a reference to the clientsInRange global list (which was actually the same list it was referenced before).. the new data is some inner properties inside the object which supposed the affect the ListView